# improper integral - prove divergence or convergence

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

prove if:
$\int _{R^2}e^{-(x+y)^2} dx dy$   diverge or converge

I have proven that $\int _{R^2}e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy$ converge (and equal to $\pi$) using polar coordinates, but here the exponent of $e$ become a bit too complicated, and I have the feeling I should use another transformation

I thought maybe to use the comparison test here, but I couldnt think of good enough example.

as for proving it diverge , I also didnt have success with that.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diverges and to show it, you can do the change of coordinate:
\begin{align*}u&=x+y\\v&=x-y\end{align*}
To a constant, the integral will be proportional to:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-u^2}\,du\,dv$$
The integral in $u$ converges to $\sqrt\pi$ but then for $v$ you need to integrate a constant over $\mathbb R$, which will diverge.

Comment: thank you very much, can I ask what made you pick this specific coordinate for V ?

Comment: It's orthogonal to $u$.